# Raise propery changed throws XamlParsingException

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a property that throws exception when I raise the ProperyChanged event.

The exception occurs arbitrary (it means that usually, it succeed to raise the property change event without a problem), and I don't know what the reason.

Image:
http://www.upz.co.il/images/2013/10/19/tpWJc.png

This is the code for the property:

```
    public CategoryViewModel SelectedCategoryViewModel
    {
        get { return _selectedCategoryViewModel; }
        set
        {
            _selectedCategoryViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCategoryViewModel");

        }
    }
```

nothing special in it. Which reasons can make this PropertyChanged event to throws these exceptions (copied from the output window):

A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Thanks!!

Comment: you need to provide some code of the classes, the view model and how you're attempting to use it

Comment: Can you post the XAML that's binding to this property.

Comment: I fixed the problem. It was nothing to do with the property changed event, or the xaml binding. I approached by mistake to a list in the position [0] while the list was empty. Sometimes the visual studio debugger is useless and point on the wrong places, especially in windows phone. When does it support IntelliTrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It was nothing to do with the property changed event, or the xaml binding. I approached by mistake to a list in the position [0] while the list was empty. Sometimes the visual studio debugger is useless and point on the wrong places, especially in windows phone.